# Localize URL's in downloaded text file using sed

Tags: macos, curl, sed

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have several text files locally (Markdown formatted), which contain image links to either external images or local images. If they are external, meaning they are linked with an http(s) URL, they should be downloaded, and then the link in the files should be replaced with the downloaded filename and location.

I figured out how to download the images to the `assets` directory. But I can't wrap my head around how to replace the URL's in the file. I thought I could just use `sed` to search the URL, and replace it with the new local filename.

Maybe I'm doing this more complicated than necessary, in which case I would like to know how I can make this easier.

I'm on OS X/macOS. The `""` after the `sed` command is necessary to destructively edit the file -- otherwise a backup file is created.

Thank you.

```
if [[ $i == *"http"* ]]; then
    #if not local, download image
    echo $i
    cd "$packageName/assets"
    curl -OJ $(echo $i | sed -e "s/\!\[\](\(.*\))/\1/")
    cd -
    sed -i "" "s/{$i}/blabla/g" "$packageName/$inFile"
else [[ -e $i ]]
    #if local, move to assets folder
    echo $i
    cp "$(echo $i | sed -e "s/\!\[\](\(.*\))/\1/")" .
fi
```

Comment: So what's the problem, exactly? At which point does your approach fail? And what shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using the default Shell that comes with OS X. Bash. The approach fails that the command above gives an error. Either unbalanced brackets or something else. Nothing I have found has been conclusive enough for me to fix this issue myself.

Comment: A few quick hints: you need to use `${i}` rather than `{$i}` and you need to use a character other than slash for your `sed` scripts, e.g. `s|${i}|blabla|g` in order to avoid problems with the slashes in the URL.